# Positioning elements in Canvas programmatically: SetTop not being seen by the compiler

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, position

I've already used `Canvas.SetLeft` or `Canvas.SetTop` before, but now I'm getting an error.
I have Canvas inside a WrapPanel which is inside the Grid of the Window:

```
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel>

    </WrapPabel>
</Grid>
```

When the window is loaded, it's called a method `Canvas()` and inside it I implement some canvas and labels inside them. When I try to position the labels inside its canvas (`Canvas.SetTop(lab, 10)`) I get this error:
`Canvas() is a 'method' , which is not valid in the given context.`

I'm a beginner with programming and I don't know why this happens and what to do...

```
public void Canvas()
    {
        Canvas[] cans = new Canvas[5];
        Label[] lb = new Label[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            lb[i] = new Label();
            cans[i] = new Canvas();
            cans[i].Height = 132;
            cans[i].Width = 283;
            cans[i].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
            cans[i].Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5);
            lb[i].Content = "BOSTA";
            Canvas.SetTop(lb[i], 20);  //problematic line
            cans[i].Children.Add(lb[i]);
            wp.Children.Add(cans[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I got it. I've just put `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetTop` instead only `Canvas.SetTop`.

What a shame..

Comment: That's probably because you have a method named `Canvas`. Thus just hitting `Canvas.SetTop` you're trying to access `.SetTop` of your `Canvas()` method which doesn't make sense. I bet if you rename `public void Canvas()` to something else, `Canvas.SetTop` would work fine.

Comment: Quite a time has passed since you've found your solution. Please mark your own answer as "accepted" one, so we know that your question/problem is now solved!